# Apache2, VirtualHost, CentOs: root context and subcontext on one server

Tags: linux, apache, svn, jboss, virtualhost

I use apache2 httpd server 2.2.15, CentOs 2.6.32, Wildfly 8.1.0.Final, VPS with plesk 12.0.18, 1 domain: something.com. Everything is on one VPS.

I want to have following links working:

1) something.com  [redirect to wildfly application at localhost:8080/app1]

2) something.com/repos/app1 [svn repository is here/SVN server/subversion 1.8.10/ port 80 is used here]

I neet proper VirtualHost configuration in apache2.
Question: how to configure VirtualHost in apache2 (my location: /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf)?

My current working configuration for 1) is:

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName something.com
   ServerAlias www.something.com something.com

   ProxyRequests Off
   ProxyPreserveHost On

   ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/app1/
   ProxyPassReverse /  http://localhost:8080/app1/

   RewriteEngine   On
   RewriteCond     %{THE_REQUEST}  /app1/
   RewriteRule     ^/app1/(.*)$ /$1 [PT]

</VirtualHost>
```

Frankly speaking, I tried different VirtualHost configurations but none of them was working for me. I don't want to attached 10 bad configurations so I attached only one working for 1).

And in jboss-web.xml (w WEB-INF) in my app1 application is:

```
<jboss-web>
    <virtual-host>myVirtualServerName</virtual-host> 
</jboss-web>
```

and using jboss-cli.sh I added:

```
/subsystem=undertow/server=default-server/host=myVirtualServerName/:add(default-web-module=app1.web.war,alias=["something.com"])
```

This is the 3rd day I am trying to do this. I know there are similar topics but similar doesn't mean the same. Or maybe I don't know which solution should work? Or maybe there is more than 1 solution?

Advices highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

---

I tried:

I)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName something.com
   ServerAlias www.something.com something.com

   ProxyRequests Off
   ProxyPreserveHost On

   ProxyPass /repos/app1/trunk http://localhost/repos/app1/trunk/
   ProxyPassReverse /repos/app1/trunk  http://localhost/repos/app1/trunk/

   ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/app1/
   ProxyPassReverse /  http://localhost:8080/app1/

   RewriteEngine   On
   RewriteCond     %{THE_REQUEST}  /repos/app1/trunk/
   RewriteRule     ^/repos/app1/trunk/(.*)$ /$1 [PT]
   RewriteCond     %{THE_REQUEST}  /app1/
   RewriteRule     ^/app1/(.*)$ /$1 [PT]

</VirtualHost>
```

but it doesn't work

II)
This solution doesn't work too:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName something.com
   ServerAlias www.something.com something.com

   ProxyRequests Off
   ProxyPreserveHost On

   <Location /repos/app1/>
    ProxyPass http://localhost/repos/app1/
    ProxyPassReverse http://localhost/repos/app1/
    ProxyPassReverseCookiePath / /repos/app1/
  </Location>

   <Location />
    ProxyPass http://localhost:8080/app1/
    ProxyPassReverse http://localhost8080/app1/
    ProxyPassReverseCookiePath / /app1/
  </Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is some fact you need to understand.
When using Apache mod_proxy and Wildfly the request will heading this way:

```
 REQUEST -> APACHE <-> Wildfly Undertow
 RESPONSE <- APACHE <-> Wildfly Undertow
```

With this picture in mind the configuration should be easy.
Every request and response is only talking with the apache, not with the undertow. Therefore there is no additional setting than the http_connector on undertow side needed.

But you need to make sure that apache configuration is always reaching the Undertow. Based on your approach the SVN applikation should look like this:

```
ProxyPass /repos/app1/trunk http://localhost:8080/repos/app1/trunk/
ProxyPassReverse /repos/app1/trunk  http://localhost:8080/repos/app1/trunk/
```

Please note the port behind the host.

Comment: /repos/app1/trunk is not on Wildfly Undertow. This is standard Subversion/SVN server installation. Port 80 is used here. I tried to used port 80 behind the host as you suggested  but with no positive results. Without VirtualHost configuration (on apache2) link something.com/repos/app1 works well but of course there is no redirection between something.com -> localhost:8080/app1  . Proper VirtualHost config is necessary.

Comment: Why do you need a ProxyPass if the normal access is working?
What about `Alias /repos/app1 /path/to/repo`

Comment: I think alias is not necessary here. From my server the location is: http://localhost/repos/app1/   , from outside should be something.com/repos/app1/ (the same besides server name). If my current VirtualHost configuration is used then I cannot access my repository from outside because this request is caught by my wildfly application and "there is no such page" page is returned back but I want to see my code repository. :-(

Comment: On which interfaces is the SVN listening? Maybe you cannot reach SVN on `localhost:80/repos/app1`